# How can I await a Task within a class constructor/timer callback

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-await

I have a Async Function (doesn't return a actual value, just the Task object) that I need to run from within a class constructor, as well as when a Threading.Timers.Timer fires.

I cannot mark a constructor sub as async and when I use AddressOf to set the timer callback it warns me that "The Task returned from this Async Function will be dropped, and any exceptions in it ignored. Consider changing it to an Async Sub so its exceptions are propagated.".  I've heard that using Async subs/voids is not a good idea and should be avoided if at all possible.

Constructor Code

```vb
Public Sub New(File As String)
  Me.New()
  Await ImportXml(File)
End Sub
```

Timer Code

```vb
Private WithEvents SaveTimer As New Threading.Timer(AddressOf Save, Nothing, 30 * 1000, Threading.Timeout.Infinite)
```

I think with the constructor I can separate the loading of the file into a separate sub (unless there is a better way), but not sure what to do about the timer.  I'm wondering if I'm doing it wrong and there's a way to schedule tasks, some kind of Task timer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since constructors cannot returns tasks you can instead have the type hide its constructor and expose one or more factory methods that *are* asynchronus and do return tasks that users of the type can use to create instances:

```
public class Foo
{
    private Foo()
    {
    }

    public static async Task<Foo> CreateAsync()
    {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        await foo.InitializeAsync();
        return foo;
    }
}
```

As for the timer, you can simply avoid using an actual timer and just create an `async` method:

```
public static async Task DoStuff()
{
    while (true)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => SomeWork());
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
    }
}
```

Comment: `DoStuff` should use a `CancellationToken` otherwise it's an infinite loop.

Comment: @Zer0 If he needs to be able to cancel it, sure, it can accept a cancellation token.  If it doesn't need to be cancelled, then it doesn't need to be cancelled.

Comment: @Servy If we take the OP's code to account, there's no need for a loop at all and the delay needs to come before the work. Also, what's the value in using `Task.Run`?

Comment: @I3arnon If the OP doesn't need to loop then the OP can not loop.  I never really bothered to memorize the exact details of the `Timer` constructor.  That's one of the advantages of this style of code, it's intentions are much clearer.  If he needs the delay to come first, he can have the delay be first.  As for the `Run` call, the whole point is that it represents any `await`able operation; it's a placeholder for anything that is asynchronous.  I simply picked something.

Comment: @Servy He should always cancel it, regardless.  An infinite loop is an infinite loop, whether it's async or not doesn't matter.  The application could terminate at some arbitrary point in `SomeWork`.  And using a custom `TaskScheduler` could make it even worse.  This is about as bad as calling `Thread.Abort`.

Comment: @Zer0 `Thread.Abort` is problematic because you stop an application at an arbitrary point in time *and then continue executing the application in a possibly unsensible state*.  The problems largely don't exist when it's the entire process being torn down.